# How to hide content from URL but still need to send to server in node.js and express.?

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, express, url-rewriting

I have tried to hide some content from URL and still I want to send that content to server in express app.but haven't got any solutions yet.

e.g. I have an URL like,
www.abc.com/viewblog/V8eNr6adLJ/post-title

now I want to remove "V8eNr6adLJ" from URL but still need to pass on server.

How can I do that ? need I to use any npm modules or any other way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use method POST in express
http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.post.method

Comment: thanks but I need to show rest URL content and only want to hide some of them.

Comment: then what do you want please specify??

Comment: I have clearly mentioned that in example that I want to show URL but need to hide some content from it.and that content still want to send to server. e.g url: www.abc.com/viewblog/V8eNr6adLJ/post-title in that I want to remove "/V8eNr6adLJ" so now url: www.abc.com/viewblog/post-title.but still I need that "V8eNr6adLJ" value on server.

Comment: yes Ravindra but here I do not want to show that on URL and my URL should be like www.abc.com/viewblog/post-title.any other way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use method POST instead

Comment: thanks but I need to show rest URL content and only want to hide some of them.